# Regular expression with multiple matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on creating indexing software for LaTeX. When reading in a TeX file that already contains index entries, I want to be able to identify those entries and use the content of each index entry to build the heading and subheading structure of the index.

Using the following sentence as an example:

```
Sentence \index{Palenque} with two LaTeX index entries \index{Yaxchilan!Itzamnaah B'ahlam@\textit{Itzamnaah B'ahlam}!warfare} in it.
```

I want to retrieve the two index entries (`\index{Palenque}` and `\index{Yaxchilan!Itzamnaah B'ahlam@\textit{Itzamnaah B'ahlam}!warfare}`). Once I have those, I can use the content of the \index to reconstruct the index entry in my program.

I've managed to construct a regular expression that gets part of the way to what I'm looking for, but I suspect that is more by accident than by design. The expression I have so far is:

```
\\index[{]([[:graph:][:punct:]]+)
```

This returns `\index{Palenque}` and `\index{Yaxchilan!Itzamnaah` - not the complete second \index entry. I haven't been able to come up with something to completely retrieve all of the more complex entry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive regex but you'd need the newer `regex` module instead of the builtin one:

```
import regex as re
pattern = re.compile(r"\\index(\{((?:[^{}]+|(?1))+)\})")

data = "Sentence \index{Palenque} with two LaTeX index entries \index{Yaxchilan!Itzamnaah B'ahlam@\textit{Itzamnaah B'ahlam}!warfare} in it."

result = [m.group(2) for m in pattern.finditer(data)]
print(result)
```

See a demo for this one on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ULozwa/1).

---

Instead, you could also very well write your own little program that counts parentheses:

```
data = "Sentence \index{Palenque} with two LaTeX index entries \index{Yaxchilan!Itzamnaah B'ahlam@\textit{Itzamnaah B'ahlam}!warfare} in it."

needle = r"\index"
result = []
pars = 0; offset = 0; i = 0

while (True):
    pos = data.find(needle, offset)
    if (pos == -1):
        break

    buffer = []
    for char in data[pos + len(needle):]:
        i += 1
        if char == "{":
            pars += 1
        elif char == "}":
            pars -= 1
        
        if pars >= 1:
            # within pars
            buffer.append(char)
        else:
            # finished
            result.append("".join(buffer[1:]))
            offset = pos + i
            break

print(result)
```

Both approaches will yield

```
['Palenque', "Yaxchilan!Itzamnaah B'ahlam@\textit{Itzamnaah B'ahlam}!warfare"]
```

Be aware though that the `latex` string must only contain paired parentheses (ie for every `{` there has to b a `}`).

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should do it:

```
\\index{(?:[^}{]|{(?:[^}{]|{(?:[^}{]|{[^}{]*})*})*})*}
```

It can handle a maximum of two levels of curly brackets, but can be extended to three or more. Recursive expressions is also a possiblity.